# How to Add Phonegap Push Notification in WEBAPI

Tags: cordova, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, phonegap-plugins

I have tried the phonegap push Notification in manually its works great,Now i am little bit confuse that where i need to implement pushNotification in my WEBAPI,
I am building App with corodva and backed is WEBAPI,Now i am in scenario that i need to add pushNotification to my App, i did pushNotificaton manually its work fine, its required SENDERID which is GCM projectNumber And its API Key and finally registration token of user  Now My question is

1. Do i need to store the registration token in my DB for each user.
2. when and where i need to call the push Notification function in WEBAPI
3. Then how i can modify the UI of pushNotification of Phonegap.

any resource regarding pushNotification and WEBAPI need help

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: yes i completed it,Its working for me.